# How to resolve git stash conflict without commit?

Tags: git, git-stash

As [asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7517124/11343), I also want to know how to resolve a conflicting `git stash pop` without adding all modifications to a commit (just like "git stash pop" without a conflict does).

My current approach is very uncool because I do it this way:

```sh
git stash pop  # -> CONFLICT
git stash drop
# [resolve conflict]
# [add conflict files]
git reset HEAD # <all files that are in commit-mode>
```

---

**How to reproduce:**

```sh
mkdir foo; cd foo; git init
echo "1" > one
echo "2" > two
git add -A; git commit -m "first"
echo "1.1" > one
echo "2.1" > two
git stash
echo "2.2" > two
git commit -a -m "second"
echo "Only this file would stay in HEAD without the conflict" > third
git add third
git stash pop
git status
```

2016-06-27: Added a new file called 'third' to the example to show that workarounds like the solution from scy only work for empty HEADs but don't fix the initial problem that the HEAD doesn't have the same content like for a `git stash pop` without a conflict.

Comment: So you `git add` your resolved conflict files, effectively staging them in the index, and you'd want to not have them in our index?

Comment: Yes, thats right. I just want the behavior that `git stash pop` has when no conflict occurs (but with notification which files need to be merged).

Comment: Seems like the answer for this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945826/git-stash-questions. In the chosen answer, on the 4th comment, Adam explains why git does this.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you for this information - so it seems there will be no solution available because its "by design"

Comment: The direct link to the comment @Patrick is referring to is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945826/git-stash-questions#comment4246601_3945995

Answer (score 862):

#### Clean solution

The following solution seems to be much cleaner to me and it's also **suggested by the Git itself** — try to execute `git status` in the repository with a conflict:

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
```

**Note:** The [`restore` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) has been introduced in Git [version 2.23.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.23.0). Older versions of Git suggested to use the command `git reset HEAD <file>...` instead of `git restore --staged <file>...`. You could also use [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to unstage any and all files in the staging area (called the [index](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefindexaindex)). Restore command's equivalent is `git restore --staged .` (the dot is necessary and it specifies any file). Currently, **any of those commands may be used and the outcome is the same**. If you want to learn about the differences between those commands, check the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_reset_restore_and_revert).

So let's do what Git suggests (*without making and reverting any pointless commits*):

1. Manually (or ideally using some *merge tool*, see below) resolve the conflict(s).
2. Use `git restore --staged .` to mark conflict(s) as resolved and unstage *all* files in the staging area. If you want to unstage only specific files, use the command `git restore --staged <file>` instead. You don't have to execute `git add` before.
3. Finally, remove the stash with `git stash drop`, because Git doesn't do that automatically on conflict.

Translated to the command-line commands:

```
$ git stash pop

# ...resolve conflict(s)

$ git restore --staged .

$ git stash drop
```

#### Explanation of the default behavior

There are two ways of marking conflicts as resolved: `git add` and `git restore --staged <file>...`. While `git restore --staged <file>...` marks the conflicts as resolved and removes files from the index, `git add` also marks the conflicts as resolved, but keeps files in the index.

Adding files to the index after a conflict is resolved is on purpose. This way you can differentiate the changes from the previous stash and changes you made after the conflict was resolved. If you don't like it, you can always use `git restore --staged .` to remove everything from the index.

#### Merge tools

I highly recommend using any of [3-way merge tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572237/whats-the-best-three-way-merge-tool) for resolving conflicts, e.g. [KDiff3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/), [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/), etc., instead of doing it manually. It usually solves all or the majority of conflicts automatically itself. It's **huge** time-saver!

Comment: @kamalpal it seems to be needed when `git stash pop` fails with conflicts.

Comment: @kamalpal yes, Git even notifies you that stash has not been dropped in a case of conflict. And the question was about such case, so you **really need to execute `git stash drop`** unless you want to keep that stash.

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan Git did not notify me at all that it did not drop the stash entry. Version 2.17.1 here.

Comment: This is so much more clear than many blog posts I've read on this topic.

Comment: For a stash with changes to multiple files: `git stash pop` does apply the changes to the files that don't result in conflicts, so it's only the files where conflicts occur that you have to fix.

Comment: I had a merge conflict while applying a stash. I resolved the conflicts, added the files and committed them. But then nothing happened. Normally I would do something like `git rebase --continue` for git to continue the progess. But I tried your command `git stash drop` and I just dropped my stash without the changes applied. Thank you for helping me loosing all my changes.

Comment: After `git stash drop`, I need to execute `git checkout -- "conflicted_file"` to discard the `conflicted_file`.

Comment: Current versions of git now output the suggestion `git restore --staged` rather than `git reset`, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003889/1108305) to another question says has the same effect.

Comment: The clean solution worked for me and, after using it, it makes way more sense than all others that I tested. Thank you very much, and enjoy your upvote :-)

Comment: @M.Justin Oh, thank you for mentioning it! I didn't even notice it yet. I have updated the answer so it reflects the current state.

Comment: @xuanduc611 I'm afraid you're doing something wrong. If you execute `git checkout -- "conflicted_file"`, you'll overwrite the file with the changes you just unstashed and where you have solved the conflict with the version from the most recent commit. So you'll completely lose the changes from the stash (since you dropped it already) and it completely doesn't make sense to unstash the changes, solve the conflict, drop the stash and finally overwrite and lose everything you just did. 

Comment: @winklerrr You have been following another answer probably. Nowhere I suggest making a commit, actually the opposite. Also, `git rebase --continue` doesn't make sense at all – you cannot continue with rebasing you didn't start. Stash has nothing to do with the rebase. And before making any irreversible operations, you should always double-check you won't lose anything. But there are [ways to restore a dropped stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517870/how-to-undo-git-stash-clear). I'm really sorry you lost your work, but my answer has helped hundreds of devs, only you had an issue.

Comment: The `.` refspec doesn't specify any file. It specifies the current directory. What you want is `:/`. i submitted an edit

Comment: git: 'restore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: I get "error: path <...> is unmerged" many times when I attempt to do `git restore --staged .`

Comment: `git restore --staged <file>` made me lose my stashed changes. I want the file to contain the edits, but not be committed or staged.

Answer (score 308):

Suppose you have this scenario where you stash your changes in order to pull from origin. Possibly because your local changes are just `debug: true` in some settings file. Now you pull and someone has introduced a new setting there, creating a conflict.

`git status` says:

```
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      src/js/globals.tpl.js
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Okay. I decided to go with what Git suggested: I resolved the conflict and committed:

```
vim src/js/globals.tpl.js
# type type type …
git commit -a -m WIP   # (short for "work in progress")
```

Now my working copy is in the state I want, but I have created a commit that I don't want to have. How do I get rid of that commit without modifying my working copy? Wait, there's a popular command for that!

```
git reset HEAD^
```

My working copy has not been changed, but the WIP commit is gone. That's exactly what I wanted! (Note that I'm not using `--soft` here, because if there are auto-merged files in your stash, they are auto-staged and thus you'd end up with these files being staged again after `reset`.)

But there's one more thing left: The man page for `git stash pop` reminds us that *"Applying the state can fail with conflicts; in this case, it is not removed from the stash list. You need to resolve the conflicts by hand and call `git stash drop` manually afterwards."* So that's exactly what we do now:

```
git stash drop
```

And done.

Comment: There's just a lot of inherit ugliness in deliberately having to do commit reset HEAD^... for something that should only affect the working tree.

Comment: Why not just resolve the conflicts and then `git add <resolved conflict files>` followed by `git reset HEAD`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't fix the initial problem that this isn't the same behavior like `git stash pop` without a conflict. Just add another file to HEAD before doing the conflicting `git stash pop` and than your `git commit -a -m WIP` would also add the new file to the commit. But without a conflict, just the new file would stay in HEAD but not the `git stash pop` files.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to commit first then undo commit. Simply reset from [Dawid Ferenczy answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27382210/1713660) will do the same

Comment: For windows users, the `^` is used as a special line continuation and will leave you sitting at a More? prompt instead of execution the command. Instead use: `git reset --soft HEAD~1`. See [how-do-i-delete-unpushed-git-commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197413/how-do-i-delete-unpushed-git-commits)

Comment: instead of doing `git commit -a` wouldn't you just do `git reset HEAD` and have everything cool?

Answer (score 94):

Instead of adding the changes you make to resolve the conflict, you can use `git reset HEAD file` to resolve the conflict without staging your changes.

You may have to run this command twice, however. Once to mark the conflict as resolved and once to unstage the changes that were staged by the conflict resolution routine.

It is possible that there should be a reset mode that does both of these things simultaneously, although there is not one now.

Comment: The reset mode is the one I search for - other workarounds are like the one I described and not practical for more than 5 files.

Comment: And use "git stash drop" afterwards to finish the "git stash pop".

Comment: Although the question does not ask for this explicitly, it might be useful to update the answer to include "git stash drop" as the stash is not dropped automatically in the case of a conflict.

Comment: `git reset` is enough. Once. After you resolved the conflict (changed the files).

Answer (score 47):

```
git checkout stash -- .
```

worked for me.

**Note**: this can be dangerous since it doesn't try to merge the changes from the stash into your working copy, but **overwrites** it with the stashed files instead. So you can lose your uncommitted changes.

Comment: This helped when "git pull --autostash" introduces unwanted merge commits and git checkout stash -- . unconditionally overwrites conflicts from stash

Comment: This helped me get out of "git hell" where the same conflict kept coming up even after following the git suggestions. I would do `git stash pop`, resolve the conflict, git add/commit, and `git stash pop` would produce the same issue. After running the above, I was able to run `git stash pop` and it worked.

Comment: This helped me in a situation where Github Actions build replace Docker image tags in Kubernetes manifests and push them from dev to staging branch. Creating PR to merge modified staging branch to main branch caused conflicts and this answer saved my bacon real good.

Comment: And then `git stash drop` it went without saying.

Comment: Tried everything else, only this worked. My case was more complex triggered in github actions workflow. Nice work!

Answer (score 35):

```
git add .
git reset
```

`git add .` will stage ALL the files telling git that you have resolved the conflict

`git reset` will unstage ALL the staged files without creating a commit

Comment: This is actually not a bad answer, it's pretty much like `git add -u` then `git reset`

Comment: clean and to the point

Answer (score 11):

No problem there. A simple `git reset HEAD` is what you're looking for because it leaves your files as modified just like a non-conflicting `git stash pop`.

The only problem is that your conflicting files will still have the conflict tags and git will no longer report them as conflicting with the "both_modified" flag which is useful.

To prevent this, just resolve the conflicts (edit and fix the conflicting files) before running `git reset HEAD` and you're good to go...

At the end of this process your stash will remain in the queue, so just do a `git stash drop` to clear it up.

This just happened to me and googled this question, so the solution has been tested.

I think that's as clean as it gets...

Answer (score 6):

It seems that this may be the answer you're looking for, I haven't tried this personally yet, but it seems like it may do the trick. With this command GIT will try to apply the changes as they were before, without trying to add all of them for commit.

`git stash apply --index`

here is the full explanation:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but this won't help when I already did `git stash pop` - or is there a way to revert this and to do `git stash apply --index` when I found out that `git stash pop` will run into a conflict?

Comment: I've added an example on how to produce this - imagine you're editing more than 10 files, so you don't know which of them you modified outside the stash.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of this post [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840816/git-stash-blunder-git-stash-pop-and-ended-up-with-merge-conflicts) it says that if you run `git stash pop` and it ends up with conflicts, the stash does not get removed...so you can run `git reset --hard` to undo the pop and then try the solution I suggested.

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't work after you have a file in conflict state. Even if you fix the conflict manually.

Comment: This may still cause merge conflicts if your working tree contains staged/unstaged changes and you `git stash --keep-index && git stash pop --index`. The solution to this corner case is something along the lines of  `git stash --keep-index; do-stuff; git stash && git stash pop stash@{1} --index && git stash pop --index`

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way I have found is to resolve the conflict, then do `git add -u`, and then do `git reset HEAD`, that doesn't even involve a commit.

Answer (score 2):

`git stash branch` will works, which creates a new branch for you, checks out
the commit you were on when you stashed your work, reapplies your work there, and
then drops the stash if it applies successfully. check [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing#Creating-a-Branch-from-a-Stash)

Answer (score 1):

According to [git stash questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945826/git-stash-questions), after fixing the conflict, `git add <file>` is the right course of action.

It was after reading [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945826/git-stash-questions#comment4246601_3945995) that I understood that the changes are automatically added to the index (by design). That's why `git add <file>` completes the conflict resolution process.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for people having trouble with `git stash -u` not applying cleanly**

What if you have a stash created with `git stash -u`? Then most of the answers to this question are invalid! Because as soon as you follow the advice given in the highest ranked answer (this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382210/816017) - i.e. using `git stash drop` (my advice: **don't do it**) your unstaged files are gone.

That was a long-winded introduction to say the following:

If you have troubles with a `Merge conflict` when doing `git stash pop`, and you have used `git stash -u`, then one way to get out of that situation is this:

- `git stash branch my-stash-branch`
- Do whatever you need to fix the diff.

  - Hard diffs: Manually copy the offending files to a non-git folder, and then do `git restore myfile`, then apply the changes manually
  - Easy diffs: If the conflict is just in some throwaway file like `Cargo.lock` or `yarn.lock` just `git restore Cargo.lock`.
- Do `git stash -u` again
- `git checkout my-actual-branch`
- `git stash pop` which should apply cleanly now, otherwise rinse & repeat
- Remove the `my-stash-branch` once you are confident your changes have been applied correctly.

In short: the answer claiming *"Don't follow other answers..."* in a large bold font, is not the answer for everybody! ESPECIALLY not if you used `git stash -u`. Your changes may be lost!

Footnotes:

- Unstaged files that have been lost by `git stash drop` can probably be found if you dig through `git fsck` - they're not in the `reflog` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: SAVED MY DAY! My case was exactly `gits stash -u` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

please make sure that if you are using source tree for git, they will say that commit your changes or conflicts. Please don't do that,

Instead of opening your terminal and type

```
git add .
git stash
```

this source tree is telling 'commit your changes because they don't know if this change is conflicted or not but they are trying to take a backup for safety.

This **git stash** command will delete your merged conflicts.
Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Its not the best way to do it but it works:

```
$ git stash apply
$ >> resolve your conflict <<
$ >> do what you want to do with your code <<
$ git checkout HEAD -- file/path/to/your/file
```

Comment: this answer seems plain wrong to me, as it would discard all the changes to `file/path/to/your/file` , which is not what the OP asked, AFAIU