# How to undo git stash clear

Tags: git

I executed `git stash save "ABC"`.

Then by mistake I did `git stash clear` .
How can I retrieve the data that was in stash ABC?

Comment: None of the answers worked for me, but the one explained [here](https://mobilejazz.com/blog/how-to-recover-a-deleted-git-stash/) did. Thought it could help others, too.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

As it may be found in [the documentation of git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), you may be lucky if this works:

> Recovering stashes that were cleared/dropped erroneously
>
> If you mistakenly drop or clear stashes, they cannot be recovered through the  normal safety mechanisms. However, you can try the following incantation to get a list of stashes that are still in your repository, but not reachable any more:
>
> git fsck --unreachable |
>   grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 |
>   xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP

If you find the stash you cleared by mistake, then you can do:

```
git stash apply <stash>
```

**EDIT**: Use this command instead `git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP`

Comment: @AshishBanker: Then it's gone. Let this be a lesson to you. Don't use `git stash` to store changes you care about, use `git commit`, even if it's partial. You can always `git commit --amend` and `git rebase -i` afterwards.

Comment: On OSX: ```git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP```

Comment: The arguments of cut are not correct. There should be two spaces after the \. This is because the markdown interpreter removes one of the spaces. As suggested by @JJS use -d ' ' or -d " " as first argument of cut.

Comment: I've done this mistake via IntelliJ IDEA. Luckily it has its own VCS. So you can use VCS > Local History > Show History per each file you changed (yes, you must remember each you've changed).

Comment: while using `git bash` on Windows, It worked for me like a charm. It is quite powerful tool to recover `stashes`. `git stash apply <commit SHA>`. Did not feel the need of `git stash pop` because I accidentally cleared my stash list.

Comment: All these commands append `--grep=WIP`: **this is only the case if one didn't name the stash because by default, stashes are named "WIP on ..."!** @AshishBanker actually named the stash, so the grep will have skipped it. Same for me, dropping `--grep=WIP` I found my deleted stash at the top of the list.

Answer (score 57):

All of the above answers end with a `git stash apply [commit]` which is good, but is not an exact undo of `git stash clear`. For that you need to re-stash the orphaned stash-commit. I found [these instructions](https://dev.to/meduzen/recover-a-lost-git-stash-in-two-steps-569) which almost worked but needed a flag to get all the way there. Summarizing:

1. Find the orphaned stash commits: `git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk`
2. Re-stash the commit: `git update-ref --create-reflog refs/stash 4b3fc45c94caadcc87d783064624585c194f4be8 -m "My recover stash"`

Comment: Great one @studog! worked for me.

I would add 3. git stash apply

Comment: @JoseRondon `git stash apply` would apply the stash to your working tree, which is beyond the scope of restoring an accidentally dropped stash. However, yes, a good method to protect against repeated mistakes is to apply the stash and then commit it instead of stashing.

Answer (score 8):

Run this command to find the commit:

```
git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk --grep=WIP
```

will list something like:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
commit c36e565014d9a927c36f16e78bc327eb375d33b8
Merge: dff6bc1 4e05a0c
Author: suhailvs <suhailvs@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 19 13:32:01 2018 +0530

WIP on master: dff6bc1 added menu
```

then checkout that commit `c36e565014`:

```
git checkout c36e565014
```

Answer (score 8):

I had to use

```
git fsck --unreachable | grep commit | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs git log --merges --no-walk
```

to fetch all the orphan stash
which will give an o/p similar to this:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (395/395), done.
commit 3928306034b292770cc4cd2987c034ffad250e0b    //commit stash hash
Merge: 16056a0 ac3c354
Author: Jimmy <mail>
Date:   Thu Nov 14 17:31:05 2019 +0530

    On profile: stashing for

commit 50f6f3a7161dd44bfcef2b8328a2329db4c7ec34
```

and use

```
git apply stash 3928306034b292770cc4cd2987c034ffad250e0b
```

And I got my stashed changes back. Thanks to https://mobilejazz.com/blog/how-to-recover-a-deleted-git-stash/

Comment: I think that for your last command the correct way to right it is: 'git stash apply 3928306034b292770cc4cd2987c034ffad250e0b'

Comment: @DjamelF. that's the right way to correct it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also deleted a stash, but using the GitKraken gui, so I don't know exactly what git commands it executed.  The chosen answer didn't work for me but put me on the right path at least.

In my case, manually searching through --unreachable objects worked.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way, but I'm just glad I was able to recover the changes.

```
ids=`git fsck --unreachable | grep blob | cut -d ' ' -f3`
number_of_ids=`echo $ids | wc -l | tr -d '[:space:]'`
for i in {1..$number_of_ids}; do git show `echo $ids | sed -n ${i}p` > evaluate$i.rb;done;
```

So this saves all the unreachable objects to files prefixed by "evaluate".  I then opened all the files in a text editor (sublime for me `subl evaluate*`), and evaluated each file in turn, manually copying and pasting the file into the old version of the original file if it was a file from the stash I deleted.

Tips:

- Change the `.rb` to match the file extension of the files you are looking for, to get appropriate syntax highlighting if you want it.
- If your files aren't included, you can widen the scope of your search by removing the `| grep blob` (the blobs were where I found my files).

Answer (score -2):

Right click on your project in project structure on the left. then select Local History --> Show History
check the screen shot.it shows the list of Local Changes left side you can see the corresponding changes at right side.

To apply changes right click on the selected item it gives two options
1)Revert
2)Create Pacth

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with git, it's a feature in Jetbrains IDEs.

Comment: the git way is to fetch all the orphan stash, and git stash apply the one you want.

Comment: I actually upvoted this as it ended up being how I recovered most of my files. Even if the question specifies git I don't think this should be discredited as an answer