# Resolving stash conflict in eclipse egit

Tags: eclipse, egit

I don't know how I got into this problem but I am stuck. I stashed some changes in order to look at some code on a different branch. I then went back to the original branch and tried to apply the stashed changes. I don't understand why it decided there were conflicts. The conflicts are exactly what I want to apply. I can copy right to left to resolve it but that removes all the stashed changes. Can someone help me untangle this mess? TIA.

Comment: This (quickly) solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382210/3127111 - I had to close and reopen the project as the involved files still carried the _conflict_ marker.