# Git stash pop Auto merged after the following done

Tags: git, git-bash

**I'm trying to restore my unsaved files (stashed files)**

I had to make a small code change for that first my remote is one commit a head with 1 file change(**file1**). I need to update my local first with remote and push my changes, for that I have to stash my changes in my local as I have the same file modified (**file1**) in my local. So I have done the following.

```
$git stash
  Saved working directory and index state WIP on dev: 4eb5499

$git pull
  Updating 4eb5499..db82e7c
  Fast-forward

$git add file2 //this is different file.
$git commit
$git push

//with this done on my dev branch I also want to update my master branch with remote

So

$git checkout master
  Switched to branch 'master'
  Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.

$git pull 
  Updating 4eb5499..db82e7c
  Fast-forward

$git merge dev //to update my changes on master
$git push

  with this done my remote is updated with my changes. both on dev/master branch.

  Now I have switched my branch again. 

$git checkout dev
$git stash pop
  Auto-merging **file1**
  CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in **file1**

  As i have done
$git status

  On branch dev
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

   So I have performed the following
$ git reset HEAD

$ git status
  On branch dev
  Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.

  Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

$ git stash list
  stash@{0}: WIP on dev: 4eb5499 //I want the changes which are here.
  stash@{1}: WIP on master: 9dac6b5

$ git stash pop
  error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
```

**I just want my stashed files to be used again.**

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because the stash commit that you are attempting to apply via `git stash pop` conflicts with the current work-tree.

Many people run `git stash` instead of `git commit` in the mistaken belief that `git stash` does not make a commit.  This is not the case: in fact, `git stash` makes *at least two* commits.  (Depending on the flags you give `git stash`, it may make three commits instead of two.)  The thing that is the most special about the commits that `git stash` makes is that they are *on no branch at all*.

Nonetheless, they are still commits, just like other commits.  When you go to "pop" a stash, this simply means `git stash apply && git stash drop`.  That is, you are telling Git to `apply` the stash to your current work-tree contents.  If Git believes this went well, you then tell Git to `drop` the stash, i.e., discard the stash commits.

In some cases, the stash commits will not apply cleanly, and you will get a merge conflict, just as you would if you were running `git merge` or `git cherry-pick`.  You must resolve this merge conflict, just as you would any other merge conflict.  Note that in this case Git has *not* dropped the stash: `git stash list` will still show it.

For more about resolving stash conflicts, see [How to resolve git stash conflict without commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7751555/1256452)

Answer (score 0):

I found that git has added few lines on the files, *which looks like there is some bug in the files* (by compiler), So went into file and deleted the lines added by git

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream

between this
code may be replicated again please check and delete.

=======
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```